# pop up does not go for post back in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have button called sales and it have a JavaScript popup when I click on cancel it postback and the values in the form are inserted but when i click on ok it does not post back and the values in the form does not go in the database ( the JavaScript button is actually print call and when button is clicked it asks for print when print dialog box is open it does not post back and data is not inserted in the database)

here is the javascript code

```
function confirmAction(printable) {
    var r = confirm("You want to Print Invoice?");
    if (r == true) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(printable).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

        window.print();

        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

        __doPostBack();
    }
    else {
        __doPostBack();
    }
}
```

here is the code for button click

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnaddsale" runat="server" Text="Sale" OnClick="btnaddsale_Click"  OnClientClick="javascript:confirmAction('printable')"/>
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from where the function is called?

Comment: I have just edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, couple of notes for you:

1. You want a postback in either case.
2. Your `<asp:Button>` will automatically do a postback either way, so you don't need to call  `__doPoskBack();` in this scenario.
3. Major issue here is that, if you want a postback, it will happen immediately when the function exits, effectively canceling out the print dialog too soon. To avoid this, we will use a `JavaScript` trick that will check if the `document` has `focus`, and only when it does (when user exits print dialog in the browser) will we return and allow the postback to occur.

---

**To fix the issue,**

First: Make the function `return true;` when user cancels, and wait for `focus` and then `return true` if the user wants to print:

```
function confirmAction(printable) {
    var r = confirm("You want to Print Invoice?");
    if (r == true) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(printable).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

        window.print();

        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

        // Check focus after user exits print dialog and then return true for the postback
        var document_focus = false;
        $(document).focus(function () { document_focus = true; });
        setInterval(function () { if (document_focus === true) { return true; } }, 500);
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, change the `JavaScript` code to use the `return` statement in the `OnClientClick` event:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnaddsale" runat="server" Text="Sale" 
    OnClick="btnaddsale_Click"  
    OnClientClick="javascript:return confirmAction('printable')"/>
```

**Update based on comments and your changed requirement:**

Here's a snippet to make the script pop up after the postback. So you will insert values to database, and then add the print script / confirm dialog on page load using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`

Note I don't recommend to embed the script in your C# code, so I'd suggest to take your `confirmAction()` function and place it (if not already) into a separate "`yourScripts.js`" file and then just call the function name when the page is loaded using jQuery. Here's an example:

In your master page or page header: This file should contain the `confirmAction()` function

```
<script type="text/javascript src="path/to/yourScriptsFile.js">
```

Then, in code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Only display script on PostBack, not initial page load
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(), 
            "confirmAction", 
            @"<script type=""Text/Javascript"">$(document).ready(function() { confirmAction('printable'); });</script>");
    }
}
```

Also note, since you will NOT want a postback now, the `confirmAction` function should no longer `return true;` or use the trick code I posted above, and will just `return false`:

```
function confirmAction(printable) {
    var r = confirm("You want to Print Invoice?");
    if (r == true) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(printable).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

        window.print();

        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: when popup open I click on ok then print dialog opens and there I click on print but post back is not fired, but in pop up when i click on cancel post back is fired and query is executing

Comment: @user3098524: Ok, I fixed that issue. Found a little JavaScript trick to make sure that postback only happens after user exits the print dialog. Try this new code out.

Comment: actually I want that it should complete the btnaddsale first then it should go for the conformation of the print dialog

Comment: Seriously? Dude that is a huge difference which you should have stated  in the question - you want the postback to occur first, and then the print dialog to appear? That's a whole different solution. Which by the way makes no sense. Why don't you have all of the processing done and then let the user print? Just curious?

Comment: Your print button should have nothing to do with inserting values into your database, is what I am saying. Let the user do "Add Sale", save the values to the database, display the invoice, then let them decide to print it or not.

Comment: yes you got it, first I thought I should do it like this, but now I think I should first insert the data into database then should I ask for user to print or not..... can you give me the code hint how I can show the conformation box and show the dialog box of print if user say  ok.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, you already have code that allows user to print or not print... If you want the print button to not make a postback, just return false from your function instead of true.

Comment: now I have changed the scenario in my mind ,now what I want is that when button is clicked it should insert the data into database and after querying  the data it should show conformation for print .... I think I can achieve this using c# code not in the aspx code

Comment: can you tell me how can I show conformation box using c# and if user click on ok then it should go for print dialog

Comment: Look up `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript()`, use it with your existing JS function and it'll do what you need.

Comment: @user3098524: See my updated answer with the snippet.